# Is it possible to loop through excel worksheets and run slightly different code on each one?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to loop through 4 certain worksheets in a workbook.
Bulk of the code I am running is the same in each sheet.
I am also opening and linking different cells from other workbooks and these will be different on each sheet, hence why my code will be slightly different as it will change variables.

The problem I have is It's working but ignores the rest of my if statements except the first so doesn't run the way I want it to. Example below

```
Sub CompleteSummary()
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim x As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Sshts As Variant
Dim Ssht As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set x = Workbooks.Open(s, ReadOnly:=True)

If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic Then
Else: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End If

 Sshts = Array("First1", "Second1", "Third1", "Fourth1")
 For i = 0 To UBound(Sshts)

Set sht = x.Worksheets(Sshts(i))

 Debug.Print "print me " & Sshts(i)

 If sht.Name = "First1" Then
    Debug.Print "opened 1st"
    ElseIf sht.Name = "Second1" Then
    Debug.Print "opened 2nd"
    ElseIf sht.Name = "Third1" Then
    Debug.Print "opened 3rd"
    ElseIf sht.Name = "Fourth1" Then
    Debug.Print "opened 4th"
End If

Debug.Print "Complete"

Next i
```

The output result is as follows:

print me First1

opened 1st

Complete

print me Second1

Complete

print me Third1

Complete

print me Fourth1

Complete

What I would like it to do is this:

print me First1

**opened 1st**

Complete

print me Second1

**opened 2nd**

Complete

print me Third1

**opened 3rd**

Complete

print me Fourth1

**opened 4th**

Complete

As you can see it just takes the first if condition throughout the loop and ignores the rest despite it cycling through all of the sheets.

Any ideas or even if there is a better way than a loop and if conditions?

Comment: Can't reproduce this.

Comment: What if you write different functions for different types of sheets? Then you could call the right function based on the sheet type. Or write only a new one function and call it passing the right variables.

Comment: The only reason I could think of that you're getting these results is that the last 3 worksheets have different names e.g. `second1`, `tHiRd1`, `fourtH1`. Using e.g. `StrComp` with `vbTextCompare` or `Option Compare Text` or `Instr` with `vbTextCompare` you can remedy this. Or just write the names as they are. The bottom line, `a<>A` when comparing strings with equality.

Comment: I'm away from my computer so can't check at the moment but will check tomorrow. I did try switching position of the sheets ie make my first condition second 1 for example the code worked but it skipped the rest including first1 so I don't think it's a sheet naming issue. I was also considering writing it all out as one function and changing the variables for the sheet, would have liked to avoid that as it's quite long but I do like the calling different functions for different sheets idea.

Comment: You do need `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module.

Comment: this looks odd, put a `stop` to pause the procedure at end of each `if`, then go to Watch window and check what is the `sht.Name` at each loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be an easier approach:

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim x As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set x = Workbooks.Open(s, ReadOnly:=True)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'just do it...

For Each sht In x.Worksheets
    Debug.Print "Checking: " & sht.Name
    Select Case sht.Name
        Case "First1": Debug.Print "opened 1st"
        Case "Second1": Debug.Print "opened 2nd"
        Case "Third1": Debug.Print "opened 3rd"
        Case "Fourth1": Debug.Print "opened 4th"
    End Select
    Debug.Print "Done checking"
Next sht
```

For extra robustness compare the lower-cased names.

Comment: Thanks for this Tim. I'll check it tomorrow and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hi Tim, this worked perfectly in terms of order execution. I also have a few more sheets in x.workbook which I want to ignore and only do the code in the four names sheets. Can I combine Case with my array set out earlier. I believe Case should work with i as it is set as an integer

Comment: This would ignore any sheets which are not named in a `Case`, so I'm not sure what the change is that you need?

Comment: Apologies, I also wanted the Debug.Print "checking: " & sht.name to happen on the Case sheets only as well rather than all sheets in the workbook as in my actual code. I've just combined it on the case code section so it's all good. Thank you again for your help and also everyone else who's answered.

Answer (score 0):

By your description you don't need an Ifs or Elses. Instead just call a sub that has the repetitive code and feed it arguments that make up the difference. Here is a schematic example.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompleteSummary()
    ' 113
    
    Dim Wb              As Workbook
    Dim WsName()        As String
    Dim i               As Integer
    
    If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Else
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If
    
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook        
    WsName = Split("First1,Second1,Third1,Fourth1", ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(WsName)
        If DoTheWork(WsName(i)) Then Debug.Print "Complete"
    Next i
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Private Function DoTheWork(WsName As String) As Boolean
    ' 113
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print "Opened " & WsName
    DoTheWork = (Err.Number = 0)                ' no error occurred
    Err.Clear
End Function
```

If there are different workbooks to be opened depending upon which worksheet is being worked on you can make this choice either in the main procedure or the sub. In the latter case you would pass 2 parameters instead of the one in my example. I think you could pass up to 255 arguments.

I developed the sub as a function which returns True or False depending upon whether the action was executed without error. You could also let the function return another value, such as the result of a calculation which is slightly different for each set of arguments and that you may use to continue whatever the Main procedure is doing.

Answer (score 0):

### Multiple Worksheets

- I suspect what happened was that your last three worksheets had slightly different names i.e. their case was different.

**The First Procedure `CompleteSummary`**

- The contents of the `Sheet Names Array` demonstrate the opposite of the previous case: the worksheet names are intentionally written in a different case to show that case doesn't matter when accessing a worksheet (or opening a workbook).
- The use of the `Opened Array` allows us to avoid the `If` clause and therefore avoid checking the worksheet names.
- With the `With` statements we can avoid using additional variables.
- The first `Debug.Print` line will print the actual worksheet names and the names in the `Sheet Names Array` in parentheses.
- The second `Debug.Print` line further shows how the `If` clause is avoided.

**The Second Procedure `StringCompare`**

- When comparing strings where there might be a difference in case, you can use one of the ways presented in this procedure.
- Most often I have seen the use of `LCase` or `UCase`, but I prefer `StrComp` whose only  purpose is to compare two strings.
- In your particular case, for all comparisons you could have e.g. used one of the following options:

  ```
  If LCase(sht.Name) = LCase("First1") Then
  If UCase(sht.Name) = UCase("First1") Then
  If StrComp(sht.Name, "First1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
  ```

  etc.
- Additionally there is an option of using `Option Compare Text` right after `Option Explicit` i.e. before any procedure. Then you could safely use your solution without any changes.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit
'Option Compare Text

Sub CompleteSummary()
    
    Const wbPath As String = "F:\Test\2020\64688445\Test.xlsm"
    Dim SheetNames As Variant
    SheetNames = Array("FiRst1", "SecOnd1", "ThiRd1", "FouRth1")
    Dim Opened As Variant
    Opened = Array("1st", "2nd", "3nd", "4th")
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wbPath, ReadOnly:=True)
        For n = LBound(SheetNames) To UBound(SheetNames)
            With .Worksheets(SheetNames(n))
                Debug.Print "print me " & .Name & " (" & SheetNames(n) & ")"
                Debug.Print "opened " & Opened(n)
                Debug.Print "Complete"
            End With
        Next n
        ' Since each workbook was only read from we can safely close it.
        '.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

End Sub

Sub StringCompare()
    Debug.Print "Assign:  ", "A" = "a"
    Debug.Print "Like:    ", "A" Like "a"
    Debug.Print "StrComp0:", StrComp("A", "a") = 0
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "LCase:   ", LCase("A") = LCase("a")
    Debug.Print "UCase:   ", UCase("A") = UCase("a")
    Debug.Print "StrComp1:", StrComp("A", "a", vbTextCompare) = 0
    Debug.Print "StrCpmvL:", StrConv("A", vbLowerCase) _
                           = StrConv("a", vbLowerCase)
    Debug.Print "StrConvU:", StrConv("A", vbUpperCase) _
                           = StrConv("a", vbUpperCase)
    Debug.Print
End Sub
```